# Prepare a syntactically invalid query

Tags: sql, ado.net, prepared-statement

I want to check the syntax of a SQL query. I thought to do in preparing it, with DbCommand.Prepare method.

Unfortunately, no error or exception.

For example: SELECT * FORM table

Is there a way to check the syntax without executing the query ?

To make it perfect, it has to work on SQL Server, Oracle and IBM DB2

Comment: It's probably reasonable to say that only the SQL engine that's going to execute the SQL instructions is actually in a position to check the syntax, on that basis you are unlikely to find a method of checking ahead of submitting the SQL for execution. At least unlikely to find a solution that's actually accurate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For SQL Server, you can use [`SET FMTONLY`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173839.aspx) and/or [`SET NOEXEC`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188394.aspx)

```
set fmtonly on
go
SELECT * FORM table
go
set fmtonly off
```

Comment: That's a cool feature, but it's database dependent, of course -- it's only in MS SQL Server . We don't know for sure what the poster is using.

Comment: Ernest is right : it is only for MS SQL. For now, I can settle. To make it perfect, it has to work on SQL Server, Oracle and IBM DB2

Answer (score 2):

Generally only the database you're using is going to know whether a given query is valid or not. One standard and portable trick is to add a WHERE clause that guarantees nothing will be done, then execute the query; for example execute `SELECT * FORM table WHERE 1=0` and see what happens.

Comment: I'd have though that, generally speaking, the type of queries where you're able to reliably inject a `WHERE 1=0` or bracket the existing WHERE clause and add an `AND 1=0` to it, would be the sort of queries where you're already controlling keywords, such as `FROM`, wouldn't they?

Comment: Yeah, this isn't applicable to every situation, by a long shot. It's useful in some situations where you're building WHERE clauses based on user input. Handle the quoting and injection issues, then test the result for validity. You're right, I can't think of a realistic situation where this would help catch "FORM", but I assumed that was a fake example anyway.